# Azure HIPPA Infrastructure Updates

Tags: azure, azure-web-roles

It seems Azure does rolling platform updates on an average of every month or so. For HIPPA compliant apps, this may be an issue as changes to security, etc to the underlying infrastructure may entail recertifying the application. I know this is a long shot, but in a PAAS (web/worker roles), can the current platform configuration be frozen? I know in IAAS I have full control, but my thoughts are there is no way to lock the underlying infrastructure, am I correct? Is there any way to coordinate with MS?

Comment: You might consider asking this over at ServerFault.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [specify](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ff729422.aspx) a GuestOS for PaaS and avoid patch Tuesday updates. However, since HIPAA is about operational processes I don't think anyone sees a need for Microsoft (or anyone else) to recertify everything following this type of update.

Comment: Hey Neil you rock!  Thanks this is exactly what I am looking for

Answer (score 0):

Compliance with HIPPA and HITECH won't be compromised by Microsoft's updates of the Azure platform as long as you have a way to log and capture the changes especially if they update or change the security model or policies.  Here is a good lecture on HIPPA and HITECH compliance on the [Amazon Cloud](https://youtu.be/g4XI4IIYVrw) that would also hold true for Azure.

In a nutshell this is what you'll be doing to become HIPPA/HITECH compliant:

- Use the highest standard of security for all VPC system accounts your cloud provider offers (username and password is not enough)
- Encryption for all data while in transit
- Encryption for all data while at rest (encrypt the database)
- Encrypt all logs if they contain PHI (encrypt filesystem if needed)
- Get and use only a list of HIPPA/HITECH approved services from your cloud provider (ie.  AWS MySQL is okay, MSSQL was not on the list at the time)
- Be sure that the transport protocol even between the load balancer and the application (inside the VPC) are approved (ie. terminating TCP was okay, named pipes was not - don't ask me why)
- Be sure you are running in a dedicated instance (seems obvious but don't use the VPC for anything else)
- **Log and retain all system updates (to answer your first question if do Azure updates invalidate HIPPA compliance ... not if you log and review them and state it in your ISO policy)**
- Log and retain all application access (when a user logs in)
- Log and retain all system access (when you and team update the app or settings)
- adopt an [ISO standard](http://www.iso.org/iso/home/store/catalogue_tc/catalogue_detail.htm?csnumber=66240) when you develop your log retention standards and quality and process improvement.  This will take the form of a few 'thou shall' mandates; for example thou shall keep all system logs for 365 days, thou shall encrypt and compress and archive logs older then 365 days, thou shall audit user access logs for intrusion detection every 30 days, thou shall audit all system access logs for intrusion detection every 30 days.
- Make sure your employees are aware that there is an ISO policy and where to find it.  Believe it or not, this is part of most ISO policies that employees know there is an ISO policy in place and where to find it.